# Treatment changing over time

Tags: references, econometrics, difference-in-difference

I have a problem with the identification technique of my research paper. I would like to estimate the causal effect of a policy (the introduction of a budget balance rule) on the composition of municipalities' public spending. The framework is the following:

1. since 1999 to 2002 no municipality was subject to the rule;
2. from 2002 onwards only municipalities above a given population threshold (5000 inhabitants) were subject to the policy;
3. in 2007 (up to 2009) this rule was made more binding, in the sense that more spending items were included in the target variable and sanctions for non-compliers were exacerbated;
4. in 2010 the rule was made even more binding;
5. from 2012 to 2015 no municipality was subject to the rule.

I would like to exploit this interesting framework. My supervisor suggests a combination of difference in difference and RDD. Do you have any idea of research papers addressing a similar issue?